# npm running issue in windows command line

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd

I've two npm command and I was manually run them:
start menu -> cmd -> cd %mycodepath% -> "npm run build" -> (wait till first finished and return message) -> "npm run deploy pub"

Now, I want it running one after another auto in windows command line (server is windows).

I tried the same step as I mentioned above but cmd always finised once the first command complete and exit. shown below:

cd C:\html5\sourcecode\

npm run build  <-- (exit after here)

npm run deploy pub

Is there anyone know how could prevent it exit and continue execute the second command?

Comment: have you create bat file?

Comment: `npm` is not an executable with file extension `.exe`. It is a batch file with file extension `.bat` or `.cmd` (I don't know). You have to use in your batch file `call npm run build` and `call npm run deploy pub`. Better would be to specify `npm` with file extension. And best would be to specify `npm` with full path and file name and file extension. For details on command __CALL__ open a command prompt window and run `call /?`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, Mofi. With your suggustion, I fixed the issue.

Here is the whole content of my cmd file:

cd "C:\html5\sourcecode"

**call** npm run build

**call** npm run deploy pub

**@pause**  @rem added to see detail info